# Python pandas cumsum with reset everytime there is a 0

Tags: python, pandas, cumsum

I have a matrix with 0s and 1s, and want to do a cumsum on each column that resets to 0 whenever a zero is observed. For example, if we have the following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[0,1],[1,1],[0,1],[1,0],[1,1],[0,1]],columns = ['a','b'])
print(df)
   a  b
0  0  1
1  1  1
2  0  1
3  1  0
4  1  1
5  0  1
```

**The result I desire is:**

```
print(df)
   a  b
0  0  1
1  1  2
2  0  3
3  1  0
4  2  1
5  0  2
```

However, when I try `df.cumsum() * df`, I am able to correctly identify the 0 elements, but the counter does not reset:

```
print(df.cumsum() * df)
   a  b
0  0  1
1  1  2
2  0  3
3  2  0
4  3  4
5  0  5
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use:

```
a = df != 0
df1 = a.cumsum()-a.cumsum().where(~a).ffill().fillna(0).astype(int)
print (df1)
   a  b
0  0  1
1  1  2
2  0  3
3  1  0
4  2  1
5  0  2
```

Comment: Why does this work? I'm not sure if it will work for my situation.

Comment: @Veggiet - check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52717996/how-can-i-count-the-number-of-consecutive-trues-in-a-dataframe/52718619#52718619) for simialr solution with explanation

Comment: To do this across the columns instead of the rows, instead use:

a = df.T != 0
df1= (a.cumsum()-a.cumsum().where(~a).ffill().fillna(0).astype(int)).T

Answer (score 10):

Try this

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[0,1],[1,1],[0,1],[1,0],[1,1],[0,1]],columns = ['a','b'])
df['groupId1']=df.a.eq(0).cumsum()
df['groupId2']=df.b.eq(0).cumsum()
New=pd.DataFrame()
New['a']=df.groupby('groupId1').a.transform('cumsum')
New['b']=df.groupby('groupId2').b.transform('cumsum')

New
Out[1184]: 
   a  b
0  0  1
1  1  2
2  0  3
3  1  0
4  2  1
5  0  2
```

Comment: ok I see, you are enumerating everytime you see a 0 to create separate groups, and then cumsum within each group. Makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: @nanojohn yes, groupid made for it. Yw~

Comment: This looks nice and flexible

Answer (score 2):

You may also try the following naive but reliable approach.

Per every column - create groups to count within. Group starts once sequential value difference by row appears and lasts while value is being constant: `(x != x.shift()).cumsum()`.
Example:

```
    a   b
0   1   1
1   2   1
2   3   1
3   4   2
4   4   3
5   5   3
```

Calculate cummulative sums within groups per columns using  `pd.DataFrame`'s `apply` and `groupby` methods and you get cumsum with the zero reset in one line:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[0,1],[1,1],[0,1],[1,0],[1,1],[0,1]], columns = ['a','b'])

cs = df.apply(lambda x: x.groupby((x != x.shift()).cumsum()).cumsum())
print(cs)

   a  b
0  0  1
1  1  2
2  0  3
3  1  0
4  2  1
5  0  2
```

Answer (score 1):

A slightly hacky way would be to identify the indices of the zeros and set the corresponding values to the negative of those indices before doing the `cumsum`:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[0,1],[1,1],[0,1],[1,0],[1,1],[0,1]],columns = ['a','b'])
z = np.where(df['b']==0)
df['b'][z[0]] = -z[0]
df['b'] = np.cumsum(df['b'])
df

   a  b
0  0  1
1  1  2
2  0  3
3  1  0
4  1  1
5  0  2
```