# Pandas dataframe forward-fill with decay

Tags: python, pandas, missing-data, fillna

I am running Python 3.5, and Pandas v 0.19.2. I have a dataframe like below. Forward-filling the missing values is straight-forward.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

d = {'A': np.array([10, np.nan, np.nan, -3, np.nan, 4, np.nan, 0]),
     'B': np.array([np.nan, np.nan, 5, -3, np.nan, np.nan, 0, np.nan ])}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df_filled = df.fillna(axis='index', method='ffill')
print(df_filled)
Out[8]: 
      A    B
0  10.0  NaN
1  10.0  NaN
2  10.0  5.0
3  -3.0 -3.0
4  -3.0 -3.0
5   4.0 -3.0
6   4.0  0.0
7   0.0  0.0
```

My question is: what is the best way to implement a **forward fill with decay**? I understand the `pd.ffill()` and `pd.fillna()` do not support this. For instance, the output I am after is the below (in contrast with the regular ffill above), where the value carried over halves at each period:

```
Out[5]: 
      A    B
0  10.0  NaN
1   5.0  NaN
2   2.5  5.0
3  -3.0 -3.0
4  -1.5 -1.5
5   4.0 -0.75
6   2.0  0.0
7   0.0  0.0
```

Comment: Hi, how is decay supposed to work here? Just half of previous values?

Comment: Yes, as an example just half the previous value. I have added the regular `ffill()` output and the desired for comparison.

Comment: Anyway you could ask to add this as a feature on [github](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there's no simple way to do this. I'd recommend doing this one column at a time, using `groupby` and `apply`.

```
for c in df:
    df[c] = df[c].groupby(df[c].notnull().cumsum()).apply(
        lambda y: y.ffill() / 2 ** np.arange(len(y))
    )
```

```
df
      A     B
0  10.0   NaN
1   5.0   NaN
2   2.5  5.00
3  -3.0 -3.00
4  -1.5 -1.50
5   4.0 -0.75
6   2.0  0.00
7   0.0  0.00
```

Comment: There is an extra bracket at the end and it returns this error `NameError: name 'x' is not defined`

Comment: I think you should ask to add this to pandas as a feature, very useful.

Answer (score 3):

There is a vectorial solution. It partly uses this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45965003/4819376)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

d = {'A': np.array([10, np.nan, np.nan, -3, np.nan, 4, np.nan, 0]),
     'B': np.array([np.nan, np.nan, 5, -3, np.nan, np.nan, 0, np.nan ])}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

decay_rate = 2

ddf = df.isnull().cumsum().diff().fillna(0)
ddf = ddf!=0
ddf = ddf.cumsum() - ddf.cumsum()\
                        .where(~ddf)\
                        .ffill()\
                        .fillna(0)
df_filled = df.ffill()/(ddf * decay_rate).replace(0, 1)
```

**Edit**: In my experiments this solution is 1.8x faster than the other. It should be interesting to compare the results with the full `df`.

Comment: When I use a non-trivial dataframe with values 0-0.2 the halving seems to break after some N rows. For example on a dataframe with 7 rows I notice the halving stops working around the 3-4th index.