# pandas-resetting cumsum at a specific number

Tags: python, pandas

I read this post but it I couldn`t understand it:
[Python pandas cumsum with reset everytime there is a 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45964740/python-pandas-cumsum-with-reset-everytime-there-is-a-0)

This is my dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'pct':range(10, 20), 'day':[0,1,2,3,4,5,0,1,4,5] })
```

I want to add another column to the `df` that shows the `cumsum` of `pct` and each time `day` is 5, `cumsum` resets.
This is my desired outcome:

```
   day  pct  result
0    0   10      10
1    1   11      21
2    2   12      33
3    3   13      46
4    4   14      60
5    5   15      75
6    0   16      16 
7    1   17      33 
8    4   18      51
9    5   19      70
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one approach using a custom grouper and taking the `cumsum` along the groups:

```
g = df.day.eq(5).shift(1).cumsum().fillna(0)
df['result'] = df.groupby(g).pct.cumsum()

   pct  day  result
0   10    0      10
1   11    1      21
2   12    2      33
3   13    3      46
4   14    4      60
5   15    5      75
6   16    0      16
7   17    1      33
8   18    4      51
9   19    5      70
```

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
df['result']=df.groupby(df.day.eq(5).shift().fillna(0).cumsum())['pct'].cumsum()
print(df)
```

---

```
   pct  day  result
0   10    0      10
1   11    1      21
2   12    2      33
3   13    3      46
4   14    4      60
5   15    5      75
6   16    0      16
7   17    1      33
8   18    4      51
9   19    5      70
```