# Count and find pattern in 2D array in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have this data below:

```
data = np.array([[1, 0,-1, 0, 0, 1, 0,-1, 0, 0, 1],
                 [1, 1, 0, 0,-1, 0, 1, 0, 0,-1, 0],
                 [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0,-1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
                 [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]])
```

i want to calculate how many `0` in each row and the count is for every `0` next to each other.
the result I was hoping for was new array like this:

```
[[1 2 1 2]
 [2 1 2 1]
 [2 2 1 2]
 [2 5 2]]
```

and i want to search the `2 1 2` pattern ratio(also in every row) with some tolerance(if the number deviates slightly) and save the coordinate of `1` in the pattern.

so, I'll found `212`, or `424`, or `636`, or `9 5 10`(tolerated), etc

expected result:

```
[[0,6],[1,5],[2,7]]
```

those are the positions of every `1` in `212` pattern of `data` array

I've tried with this code below:

```
np.unique(data, return_counts=True, axis=1)
```

I fiddling with that and the result was not as I expected. This is used for image processing and the data was huge

Comment: If there are more than one `2 1 2` patterns in a row, how do you want those indices*captured*? If there are overlapping `2 1 2` (e.g. `2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2`) patterns in a row, how do you want those indices *captured*?

Comment: @wwii that wouldn't happen in my data

Comment: ... See my edit - it should comply.

Comment: Your example data has eleven columns - does the *real* data have only eleven columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data = np.array([[1, 0,-1, 0, 0, 1, 0,-1, 0, 0, 1],
                 [1, 1, 0, 0,-1, 0, 1, 0, 0,-1, 0],
                 [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0,-1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
                 [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]])
a = data
```

---

Counting consecutive zeros in each row:
Numpy and Python loop(s).
Iterate over rows; find the indices of the zeros; split the row where indices differ by more than one; get the shapes of the result.

```
for row in a:
    zeros = np.where(row==0)[0]
    neighbors = (np.argwhere(np.diff(zeros)>1)+1).ravel()
    w = np.split(zeros,neighbors)
    counts = [thing.shape[0] for thing in w]
    print(counts)
```

---

Pattern indices:
Uses some broadcasting - operates on all rows *at once* while iterating on columns

```
# pattern to search for:
# notzero,zero,zero,notzero,zero,notzero,zero,zero,notzero
pattern = np.array([False,True,True,False,True,False,True,True,False])    

# find zeros in data and pad
padded = np.pad(a==0,1)
dif = padded.shape[1] - pattern.shape[0]
for i in range(dif+1):
    stop = i+pattern.shape[0]
    test = padded[:,i:stop]
    equal =  test == pattern
    equal = np.all(equal,1)
    if any(equal):
        row = np.argwhere(equal).ravel()[0]
        print(f'[{row-1},{i+3}]')
```

This should find multiple (*separated* and overlapping) patterns in a row - seems to work with:

```
data = np.array([[1, 0,-1, 0, 0, 1, 0,-1, 0, 0, 1, 0,-1, 0, 0, 1,-1, 0, 0, 1, 0,-1, 0, 0],
                 [1, 1, 0, 0,-1, 0, 1, 0, 0,-1, 0, 1, 0, 0,-1, 0, 0, 0,-1, 0, 1, 0, 0,-1],
                 [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0,-1, 0, 1, 0, 0,-1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0,-1, 0, 1, 0],
                 [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]])
```

Comment: how to search the pattern as I described in my question

Comment: thanks, i think it did not work well for a huge amount of data. and how stupidly i am, i forgot about ratio, i want to find `212` pattern ratio (with some tolerance), not an exact pattern. thanks anyway. I just got another way to the true purpose of this

Comment: @ircham - please post sour solution as an answer. [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: I think it's not a solution for this basic question. The real purpose is I want to detect QR Code position detection patterns in images. and this question posted because I did it from the basics. then I found another way by not processing array data from an image

Answer (score 1):

Adapting the @jezrael answer from [cumsum with reset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45964740/python-pandas-cumsum-with-reset-everytime-there-is-a-0), and assuming you can add the pandas dependency:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = np.array([[1, 0,-1, 0, 0, 1, 0,-1, 0, 0, 1],
                 [1, 1, 0, 0,-1, 0, 1, 0, 0,-1, 0],
                 [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0,-1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
                 [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]])

df = pd.DataFrame(data.T, columns=range(data.shape[0]))
a = (df == 0)
df = a.cumsum()-a.cumsum().where(~a).ffill().fillna(0).astype(int)

# Add a last row of zeros 
df.loc[len(df)] = 0

# Define custom function to apply column-wise
def find_pattern(col):
    c = col.to_numpy()
    ids = np.argwhere(c==0) - 1 
    ids = ids[ids>=0]
    return [x for x in c[ids] if x!=0]

r = df.apply(lambda col: find_pattern(col), axis=0)

r
0    [1, 2, 1, 2]
1    [2, 1, 2, 1]
2    [2, 2, 1, 2]
3       [2, 5, 2]
dtype: object
```

The result `r` is a pandas Series indexed by row index, and the expected output as values.

Finally to find the `[2,1,2]` pattern, you can again use pandas functionalities:

```
r = pd.DataFrame(r, columns=['zeros'])
r['string_col'] = r['zeros'].apply(lambda row: ''.join([str(x) for x in row]))

pattern_as_string = '212'
r['pattern_index'] = r['string_col'].str.find(pattern_as_string)

         zeros  string_col  pattern_index
0  [1, 2, 1, 2]       1212              1
1  [2, 1, 2, 1]       2121              0
2  [2, 2, 1, 2]       2212              1
3     [2, 5, 2]        252             -1
```

Where `pattern_index` is the value at which the pattern starts, and it's -1 if not found.

Comment: it works to calculate the `0`. But still confused about how to look for `2 1 2` patterns and their position in the first array. And I just found out about Pandas

Comment: @ircham edited my answer to add the pattern search. Hope it helps!

Comment: but what I need is the pattern index of the first array (`data`), not the new array @FBruzzesi

Comment: Then I am not sure what your expected output is since there are other values in between. Please provide what you expect as result.