# How to multiply by a factor a set of data that is repeated in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, compare, interpolation

My problem is to apply a multiplication factor `K=0.5` starting at the first number of a set of numbers that repeats only in certain columns [Bird1 and Bird2]. This factor will be applied to the previous value calculated UNTIL the last value that repeats.

TABLE A:

```
    Bird1  Bird2  Bird3 
    
     100  50      200  
     50   40      100  
     40   40      80  
     40   80      200  
     40   50      200 
     40   90      200 
     100  12      40
```

The result should be as per the table below. How to implement this code in python?

TABLE B:

```
 Bird1     Bird2     Bird3 

   100       50        200  
   50        40        100  
   40        40        80  
 **20**      80        200  
 **10**      50      **100** 
 **5**       90      **50** 
  100        12        40
```

Using the `df.interpolate()` command is not suitable because it uses all the values ​​of the repeating lines.
I would just like a constant `K` starting and being applied to the first value, and that this multiplication is repeated in the next values, until the last value of the repeating line.

One strategy I used is to use the `df.ne(0)` command to compare the lines and check if they have the same value, but I'm having trouble implementing it.

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(',Bird1,Bird2,Bird3\r\n0,100,50,200\r\n1,50,40,100\r\n2,40,40,80\r\n3,40,80,200\r\n4,40,50,200\r\n5,40,90,200\r\n6,100,12,40\r\n'
))
k = 0.5
```

First, find where the current value equals the next value:

```
a = (df.shift(1) == df) != 0

   Bird1  Bird2  Bird3
0  False  False  False
1  False  False  False
2  False   True  False
3   True  False  False
4   True  False   True
5   True  False   True
6  False  False  False
```

Then with some magic from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45964740/python-pandas-cumsum-with-reset-everytime-there-is-a-0) answer, Count upwards on True and reset counter on False:

```
k_power = (a.cumsum()-a.cumsum().where(~a).ffill().fillna(0).astype(int))

   Bird1  Bird2  Bird3
0      0      0      0
1      0      0      0
2      0      1      0
3      1      0      0
4      2      0      1
5      3      0      2
6      0      0      0
```

Raise k to the power of that dataframe:

```
multiplier = k ** k_power

   Bird1  Bird2  Bird3
0  1.000    1.0   1.00
1  1.000    1.0   1.00
2  1.000    0.5   1.00
3  0.500    1.0   1.00
4  0.250    1.0   0.50
5  0.125    1.0   0.25
6  1.000    1.0   1.00
```

Multiply your dataframe by these values:

```
df * multiplier

   Bird1  Bird2  Bird3
0  100.0   50.0  200.0
1   50.0   40.0  100.0
2   40.0  *20.0*  80.0
3  *20.0*  80.0  200.0
4  *10.0*  50.0 *100.0*
5  * 5.0*  90.0 * 50.0*
6  100.0   12.0   40.0
```

I wasnt sure what you meant by only certian columns, so I applied the logic to all three columns.